# Extract text of website using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to extract all the text in a specific webpage.

In JavaScript the code looks like this:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
    console.log('Stripped down page text:\n' + page.plainText);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

How can I run page.plainText in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the selenium code you have tried till now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do that with Selenium, you have to select the "top" element and after the call to `getText()`.

For example, in Python:

```py
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='pathTo/phantomjs')
driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)')
el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
print(el.text)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").get_attribute("innerText")
```